# Android XML decompiling protection

Tags: android, xml

Maybe this question was asked many times, but i can't find the answer.

Please explain, or give some links on how to protect XML files (layouts, values, animations,  etc.) in my Android app from decompiling? For now, i see that some guys are just decompling apk file and using my development.

Comment: So, even at Android Market? Solution doesn't exist at all?

Comment: no solution exists unfortunately. Best to just proguard the source, that's about it, don't over do it as that will be challenging the pirates to figure out the app! :)

Comment: @Timur the contents of your APK must be accessible in order for the Android OS to be able to access it. While it would have been possible for Google to provide some form of PKI to encrypt resources, they didn't do that. The best you can hope for is to not use XML for everything; most things can be done in code instead (though it's more difficult perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

Proguard will obfusciate your references, making it more difficult to decompile your code (and also to read stacktraces, etc).

This will help make your code harder to decompile, but not impossible.